# VueJS refresh content after database operation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

I'm using a `v-data-table` component to display data from firestore database. It looks something like this:

[image]

The approve/disapprove functionality works well, updating the firestore database with the below code:

```
database
      .collection(member)
      .doc(userId)
      .update({
        approved: status
      })
      .then({
        console.log("School member details updated successfully")
          return this.teachers.filter(teacher => {
            return teacher.id != userId;
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(
          "An error occured trying to update the school member details:",
          err
        );
      });
```

However, after the content is updated successfully on firestore database I no longer want to show the list item, I thought filtering the array as I have done in the `then()` code block would work but its not.

How could I refresh the data for the client without reloading the whole page again?

Comment: `Array.filter` is not in-place. You'll have to reassign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you don't want to show the particular list Item after successful approved. As you used `teacher.id != userId`. Have you used `teacher.id !== userId`?